# Intersection between line passing through 2 points and line passing through a point in the direction

Tags: linear-algebra

I am stuck on this question during my exam review:

Let L1 be the line passing through $$P(-1,3,-2), Q=(5,-3,10).$$  Let L2 be the line passing through $$(4,0,3)$$ in the direction of $$v=
    \begin{bmatrix}
    3\\
    -1\\
    1\\
    \end{bmatrix}.
$$
Do the lines intersect?  If so, find their point of intersection.

Attempt:
I first found the directional vector of L1, which equals **n**=(6,-6,12).  Then, using the coordinates from P, I created a system of equations as follows: $$-1+6t = 4+3s$$

$$-3-6t=-s$$

$$-2+12t=3+s$$

and found that they do not intersect.  Is this correct?

Comment: You could have used $\mathbf{n}=(1,-1,2)$ but yes, you are correct.

Comment: Hmm... I find that they *do* intersect at $(1,1,2)$. Either your second equation has a sign error or you’ve got a typo in $P$. My vote is for the former since your direction (not normal!) vector matches $P$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A line has infinitely many normal vectors in $R^3$, you meant $(6,-6,12)$ is the directional vector of $L1$.This is the correct value. However, I think there is a typo in your set up of equations:

It should be:
$$-1+6t = 4+3s$$

$$3-6t=-s$$

$$-2+12t=3+s$$
This means the two lines intersect at $(1,1,2)$

Comment: @amd You are right, I didn't notice the -3/3 difference.

Answer (score 0):

Your second equation doesn’t match the description of the first lines. Since what you’ve written for $P$ and $Q$ do match your stated value for $\mathbf n$, (which, by the way is the line’s *direction vector*, not a normal to it), I conclude that it’s the equation that’s in error. It should be $3-6t=-s$, and the resulting system has the solution $s=-1$, $t=\frac13$, therefore the two lines intersect at $(1,1,2)$.